# Does the php function file() need a special allow in php.ini?

Tags: php, .htaccess, webserver

So I guess I just googled the wrong keywords, but anyway, I couldn't find an answer.

I have a php script which basically echoes the return of

```
file($url);
```

as a string. (it does something with this first, but this is irrellevant)

Doing it on localhost with xampp works perfectly, but on my server it doesn't. I assumed setting in .htaccess the header to

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
```

should do the trick, but it still didn't work, so:
does the function file() need something like the fopen() needs allow_url_fopen = On in php.ini ?

--------------EDIT-----------------
I just added a

```
try{$f=file($url);}catch(Exception $e){
echo 'Exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";}
```

with allow_url_fopen still **Off**, but now it works for some strange reason. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it needs `allow_url_fopen` to be `on` as all other PHP functions when you manipulate on external urls

Comment: thank you, but i forgot to mention that the file is on the same server. Do you have an Idea how the try-catch made it work?

Comment: If it uses `http://` it doesn't make any difference. If you want to get file simple use path for file system.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I use ftp to get it though your method would be simpler I guess. I am trying to understand now why my catching-the-exception did help.

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference, because this function doesn't throw exceptions just return false if it cannot get content

Comment: strange enough, the exception doesn't echo at all - it is working like it was supposed to

Comment: okey now I removed the try catch again and it still works...maybe somebody changed a setting at the server. I'll ask asap       EDIT: Somebody else messed with the FTP adress in my file but fixed it right before. Thank you for your patiente with such a noob :)

Comment: When I already am speaking with an expert, do you think I should change it to directly accessing the file instead of FTP or doesn't it make a difference?

Comment: If it's possible, I would use calling file in filesystem instead of url.